# Ruby GIL of MRI 1.9

Tags: ruby, multithreading, gil

In my understanding, here's how MRI 1.9 GIL works:

1. Interpreter spawns a new thread by calling the corresponding underlying C function and ask to acquire the "GIL".
2. If "GIL" is free, we are happy. If not, the new thread will wait and invoke another separate timer thread to set up "timeslice"
3. When current executing thread hit some boundaries such as return or checking backward branches, interpreter checks the timer to decide if context switch should happen.

However, as pointed by this [article](http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8100871-nobody-understands-the-gil-part-2-implementation), we can only guarantee atomicity for pure C implementing. That being said, if some parts of our thread contains ruby code, we are still in danger of race condition.

My question is if a thread needs to acquire GIL before executing, why only C implementation methods guarantee atomicity?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The GIL helps, but still doesn't actually guarantee thread-safety.

Comment: You can refer to the article in question description which pointed out the GIL issue I asked.

Answer (score 0):

The GVL guarantees that only one thread can execute Ruby code at the *same time*. But of course different Ruby threads can execute Ruby code at *different* times.

Besides, the majority of Ruby implementations doesn't have a GVL anyway.